# Boltzmann equation for Lennard-Jones particles?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory, non-equilibrium, boltzmann-equation

In the Vlasov variant of Boltzmann equation, the Coulomb pair forces are included via the force term that appears as the prefactor of the derivative of the density with respect to velocity. In that case, one is effectively calculating a mean force or a "force field" by averaging over all the pair forces. The average is obtained by an integral over the pair potential weighted with the density.

Since this Vlasov approach allows to have good analytical insight into systems mainly governed by Coulomb forces (i.e Landau damping and other), is it possible to apply the same approach for Lennard Jones pair forces ?

I could not find references and I do not understand why this is the case.

Comment: I think Vlasov works for long range forces, like Coulomb ($1/r$), LJ force is still a power law but goes to zero much faster ($1/r^6$).

Comment: Is there a reason why the fast decay should make the analysis more difficult or not possible ?

Comment: Long-range Coulomb is related to the existence of a self-consistent electromagnetic field. The idea of Vlasov is to consider the collisionless Boltzmann with a self-consistent mean field electromagnetic field (because long-range means that everyone is interacting strongly with everyone!). JL is a phenomenological potential and there is no consistent mean-field electromagnetic potential associated. In the case of JL, you have to consider binary collisions (if the system is not too dense, i.e. if you do not have a liquid). Maybe my comment is not 100% precise, but I hope you get the gist of it.

Comment: For the long-range hypothesis (i.e. Coulomb long-range VS LJ short-range), see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375125/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/377905/226902, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/657348/226902.

Comment: Thanks, the links are very helpful. I agree that the one-particle distribution would be too simplified for the LJ system. But I do not see a reason why this mean field approach would not work for the two-particle distribution, .i.e the mean force as a function of the inter-particle distance.

Comment: The whole point of Boltzmann is to keep only the one-particle distribution (the collision integral should contain the 2-particle distribution but the molecular chaos hypothesis is used: this is exactly the hypothesis that is broken for long-range interactions). A theory for the two-body distribution could come from the BBGKY hierarchy, but it's likely to be too complex to be of any practical use in simulations (Boltzmann is already a monster equation) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy

Comment: Yes, thanks. I guess I had a problem of terminology and my question should be about the BBGKY hierarchy of Lennard Jones phases. I would continue searching though.

Comment: you can edit the question  to make it more clear or to update it  with your understanding. This should also give it more visibility and hopefully you'll get more help or good references.